# Failed: urls.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

Following code tests, if the download button links are broken or not. If yes, a test should fail otherwise pass. But the code throws an error `Failed: urls.map is not a function`. Can someone tell, why's that?

```
it('test if templates are downloadable', async () => {
  const links = element.all(by.xpath('//button//img[@src="url_here"]'));
  const urls = links.map(link => link.getAttribute('src'));
  const requests = urls.map(url => fetch(url));
  const responses = await Promise.all(requests);
  const statusCodes = responses.map(response => response.status);
  statusCodes.forEach(statusCode => {
  expect(statusCode).toBeLessThan(400);
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems strange since links.map doenst fail and it will allways return an array.
Have you tried logging your urls object befor running urls.map?

Comment: It is showing this because urls is not an array, map function only works on an array

Comment: Can you show us where are you getting urls value from.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj urls value is ['url_here', 'url_here', 'url_here'] which is an array.

Comment: Kindly check it's type using typeOf method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Protractor [docs](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) the `.map()` function that is available on [`element.all` result](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) returns a Promise that resolves to an array.

So you need to `await` for it:

```
it('test if templates are downloadable', async () => {
     const links = element.all(by.xpath('//button//img[@src="url_here"]'));
     const urls = await links.map(link => link.getAttribute('src')); // await here
     const requests = await urls.map(url => fetch(url)); // and await here
     const responses = await Promise.all(requests);
     const statusCodes = responses.map(response => response.status);
     statusCodes.forEach(statusCode => {
        expect(statusCode).toBeLessThan(400);
     });
});
```

Comment: After putting `await`, It throws this error -  Failed: Only HTTP(S) protocols are supported.